# Check to see if post is live before displaying the content

Tags: posts

I'm trying to pull the content from a post/page into a template file.

I'm using the following code, which works fine HOWEVER the content is pulled in regardless of whether it is set to 'live' or 'draft'.

Is there a way of checking to see whether the post is live before pulling in the content?

```
<?php  show_post('Offers');  // Shows the content of the offers page. ?>
```

Thank you

---

Please note this function is being used...

```
<?php 
function show_post( $path ) {
    $post = get_page_by_path( $path ); 
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ); 
    echo $content;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Are you logged in to the site when testing? WordPress behaves differently in this case depending upon if you are logged in or not.

Comment: Is **`show_post()`** a core WordPress function? I don't recognize it.

Comment: Hiya - I did wonder if it was because I was logged in, so I logged out and tested. It does the same thing.

Comment: @ChipBennett, I don't recognize it either. I found a reference to somebody's `show_post` function online. No idea if it is the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom function `show_post()` uses [`get_page_by_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) to retrieve the specified page.

[Looking at source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L3200), it doesn't look like `get_page_by_slug()` uses `post_status`. So, you'll need to query `$post->post_status` within your `show_post()` function if you want to account for it in the function output:

```
<?php 
function show_post( $path ) {
    $post = get_page_by_path( $path ); 
    $content = '';
    if ( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ); 
    }
    echo $content;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this function

```
<?php get_post_status( $ID ) ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status

Then, you can check the post's status using:

```
<?php

if ( get_post_status( $ID ) == 'publish' ) {

    echo get_the_title( $ID );
}

?>
```

Comment: Hiya - I don't want to just get the title, I need to show the content from the post I'm pulling in. I tried get_the_content but it just duplicated the content of the page I was trying to pull the post into.

Comment: Instead of echo get_the_title( $ID ); 
use $post = get_post($ID);
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Answer (score 0):

When you pull the posts from the database, make sure you set the `post_status` parameter to `publish`. Like...

`$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 , 'post_status' => 'publish');
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );`

`'post_status'     => 'publish',` is the default if you use `get_posts`. I'd say this is the best way to do it since you'd be pulling fewer posts from the database.

If for some reason you do have to pull more than one post status, check `$post->post_status` before printing it.

```
if ('publish' == $post->post_status) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I only need to pull the content from 1 post

Comment: Then only pull a post if it is published. There is no need to check after the fact. What is the query/code that pulls this one post?